# PostgreSQL Many to Many add columns on the fly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this tables:

```
CREATE TABLE sites(
     site_id VARCHAR (50) PRIMARY KEY,
     site_name VARCHAR (50),
    address VARCHAR (50)
);


CREATE TABLE contact(
     contact_id serial,
     contact_name VARCHAR (50),
     telephone VARCHAR (20),
     site_id VARCHAR (50) REFERENCES sites (site_id),
     CONSTRAINT contact key PRIMARY KEY (contact_id,     site_id) 
);
```

And this query:

```
SELECT sites.site_name, contact.contact_name,
contact.telephone FROM sites
JOIN contactos_sitio
ON sites.site_id = contacts.site_id;
```

The problem is that a contact can have multiple phones. What I am doing is just repeat the contact info (contact_name) but I get more than one row for the same contact but with different telephones.

Example:

```
Los Angeles    John Doe    1-2345678
Los Angeles    John Doe    1-5432123
New York    Mark Trump    1-2343456
etc...
```

As you see, there are two rows with the same site name and contact but with different telephones.

I want:

```
Los Angeles    John Doe    1-2345678 1-5432123   
New York    Mark Trump    1-2343456
```

If the contact is repeated, just add a new columns with the other telephones.

I am new to SQL, so I don't know if this is the right approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `string_agg()`

```
SELECT sites.site_name, contact.contact_name,
string_agg(contact.telephone,',') FROM sites
JOIN contactos_sitio
ON sites.site_id = contacts.site_id
group by sites.site_name, contact.contact_name
```